Figure alt text not displaying properly in PDF accessibility
Figure name appears when hovering over the figure, if the figure has no alternative text.
Figure alternative text displays correctly when hovering over the figure, if the figure has alternative text.
I am compiling the file using lualatex-dev.exe (2024).
MWE is below,
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III}}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

re referred by CHVs to health facilities for either weight deterioration, weight stagnation or illness according to the intervention protocol. Out of these, we identified 57 (40 in Loima and 17 in Isiolo) in health facility registers, ascertained their treatment outcomes and included them in the analysis as randomized. We faced difficulties in locating 24 out of 81 children (12 in Loima and 12 in Isiolo) in the health facility registers. Despite this challenge, we conducted a sensitivity analysis to address the missing data. This analysis utilized the IPW and Lee's bounds to provide a thorough evaluation of the potential impacts, despite the missing information. We excluded one matched pair of community health units in Isiolo because community health volunteers did not recruit any malnourished child in one of the pair members. The main analysis included 9 community health units with 210 children in the intervention group and 9 clusters with 169 children in the control group, while the sensitivity analysis consisted of 9 community health units with 234 children in the intervention group and 9 clusters with 222 children in the control group.

\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{Cluster RCT profile}
\includegraphics{example-image.jpg}
\end{figure}

re referred by CHVs to health facilities for either weight deterioration, weight stagnation or illness according to the intervention protocol. Out of these, we identified 57 (40 in Loima and 17 in Isiolo) in health facility registers, ascertained their treatment outcomes and included them in the analysis as randomized. We faced difficulties in locating 24 out of 81 children (12 in Loima and 12 in Isiolo) in the health facility registers. Despite this challenge, we conducted a sensitivity analysis to address the missing data. This analysis utilized the IPW and Lee's bounds to provide a thorough evaluation of the potential impacts, despite the missing information. We excluded one matched pair of community health units in Isiolo because community health volunteers did not recruit any malnourished child in one of the pair members. The main analysis included 9 community health units with 210 children in the intervention group and 9 clusters with 169 children in the control group, while the sensitivity analysis consisted of 9 community health units with 234 children in the intervention group and 9 clusters with 222 children in the control group.


\begin{figure}[!t]
\caption{Cluster RCT profile}
\includegraphics[alt={aaaaa bbbb ccc}]{example-image.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Figure without alternative text:

Figure with alternative text:


What's the issue here? That's entirely expected

learn to look into the log. It tells you Package tagpdf Warning: Alternative text for graphic is missing. Using the file name 'example-image.jpg' instead..

@UlrikeFischer, Alternative text is required for all figures?

@JosephWright, How do I disable the alternative text for Figure 1?

yes, every figure with meaning needs an alt-text. If the graphic has no meaning, you can tag it as artifact with \includegraphics[artifact]{example-image.jpg}.

Just to add an answer based on the comments: it's unclear from your question how the output differs from your expectation. If the image has no alt text, what do you expect the PDF viewer to display besides the file name? Your example warns
Package tagpdf Warning: Alternative text for graphic is missing.
(tagpdf)                Using the file name 'example-image.jpg' instead.

so it's telling you exactly what happens.
If the figure has relevant meaning to the document, it needs alt text. If not (like a page decoration) you can use the artifact key as Ulrike mentions. In your case, a captioned figure almost certainly has meaning for the document so needs alt text describing it.
